# SQLite: How to combine SQL of order limit with left join queries

Tags: sqlite

I have a record of A, B, C and D.

My SQL1
`SELECT * FROM main_table order by main_table.date desc limit 2` returns A and B.

My SQL2
`SELECT * FROM main_table left join sub_table using (key) where sub_table._id is not null` returns B and C.

I want to have a single SQL Statement that returns A, B and C. Basically, I want to join SQL1 or SQL2

How could I combine this two SQLs (in SQLite) optimally?

My data is as below

```
 main_table
_id  date        key
1    2016-08-04  D
2    2016-10-06  A
3    2016-09-04  B
4    2016-07-05  C

sub_table
_id  age  key
1    8    B
2    9    C
```

Desire Output

```
m._id  m.date     m.key  s._id s.age s.key
2     2016-10-06  A
3     2016-09-04  B      1     8     B
4     2016-07-05  C      2     9     C
```

My logic of selection... I want to pick the top two latest data, and also data that has an age. The others I don't care (i.e. the D is not in top 2, and doesn't have an age).

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read correctly, then a `UNION` might be what you have in mind:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM main_table LEFT JOIN sub_table USING (key)
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION
    SELECT * FROM main_table LEFT JOIN sub_table USING (key)
    WHERE sub_table._id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I can't move the ORDER BY outside, as that will result different in the event that my initial LIMIT 2 is not the same as the ORDER BY DATE LIMIT 2

Comment: Post your expected output (the real data itself).  We should be able to give you a query.  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so any ordering you do inside a subquery of the `UNION` won't "stick" in the the total query.

Comment: @Elye No, I need to see desired _output_.

Comment: Added desire output

Comment: I wouldn't change my answer based on this, because ordering descending by the date would give this output.  Maybe update to show a case where my ordering would _not_ give you your desired output.

Comment: Based on your answer, the `SELECT * FROM main_table LIMIT 2` will result in D and A. The second query will result in B and C, hence all A, B, C and D will be shown.

Comment: May I ask what happened to `D` and what is the logic by which that record was removed from the result set?

Comment: Sure. Let me put this in the question to clarify the need.

Comment: Can you try my query again?

Comment: This seems working. I did it without the T, and also the last row of order by.

Comment: I have edit where it fits me accordingly. Thanks for your help. I upvote and tick your answer. Thanks for the patience of going through with me the question and the inputs. Similarly, if you think my question would help others, you could upvote my question. Thanks!